# Where xforms:select element behavior for pdf can be changed?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I'm using orbeon 3.8, and have next problem when I'm trying to print filled form (using oxf:pdf-template), all data displays as it supposed to, but xforms:select element displays text in lower case.

This happens only when pdf template is defined to the form.

Any suggestions on where can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is probably [print-pdf-template.xsl](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/fr/print/print-pdf-template.xsl). This used to be, as of 3.8, embedded in [print-pdf-template.xpl](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commits/e1e44590bb41ceaa6480a1156c8904d1b4a06341/src/resources/apps/fr/print/print-pdf-template.xpl).

Comment: Yes **print-pdf-templates.xsl** has error `<field acro-field-name="'{$field-name}'" value="'{replace($control-value, ' ', ', ')}'"/>` while it should be `<field acro-field-name="'{$field-name}'" value="'{string-join(for $v in tokenize($control-value, '\s+') return $control-resources/item[value = $v]/label, ', ')}'"/>` , thanks for reply!